# bing in the webbrowser control, why is it so small?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I've created a testapp for WP7 that loads www.bing.com. It seems to think im on a 24" screen with full HD. Is there something Im doing wrong, would LOVE it to fit like www.live.com in the webbrowser controller.

Comment: I dont want to use m.bing.com, since its not nice to look upon :D

Comment: no. http://www.bing.com. I DONT want to use m.bing.com since it looks ugly

Comment: `bing.com` is designed for a desktop. `m.bing.com` is designed for mobile. You have to choose one or the other (or create your own search that uses the Bing API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the bing.com as default website, then specify it in your URI. If it doesn't work, then you cannot do anything about it. I mean, by default the bing will check if your using a handset device or a laptop/PC. If it is, then it will load either bing.com or m.bing.com.

But, you can still go to the real website by specifying it in the URL just like facebook, facebook by default automatically detects if your using a smartphone and redirects you to their m.facebook.com, but then you can still use facebook.com to load the wider screen.

Hope this helps!